# Connector for 3" downspout to 2" schedule 40 pvc

Tags: gutters

Looking for a connector for 3" downspout to 2" schedule 40 pvc  (not drain pipe) or some  configuration that gets me there. this is underground

Comment: I have usually observed 3 inch or 4 inch downspouts connected to 4 inch or 6 inch underground drains.    I'm no expert, but that's what the pros around here seem to do. 
 Those adapters don't seem hard to find.   Why 2 inch?

Answer (score 2):

Downspout to SDR adapter, SDR to Sch 40 adapter, 3" (or 4" depending on the downspout adapter you can find) 2" sch-40 reducer.

Good luck cramming a downspout's worth of water into a 2" pipe, though. Especially when the leaves and debris get in there. Reductions in drain lines clog, which is why they are prohibited in house drains. I doubt there's code to prevent you from doing this, but common sense would advise against, unless waterflow is from the 2" pipe into the downspout, and that would be ...odd.

Comment: agree, to OP: don't do this. If something gets stuck which is likely, what is your recovery plan? make sure you have a clean-out very nearby